# i need to get component name in the router-outlet through router-outlet activate method

Tags: angular, typescript, angular7

> I have the following tag in my html template.

```
<router-outlet (activate)="componentAdded($event)"></router-outlet>
```

> I have the following tag in my component class.

```
componentAdded($event: EventEmitter<any>) {

    console.log($event);

}
```

> I'm gettin result like below.

```
MyComponent {formBuilder: FormBuilder, route: ActivatedRoute, router: Router, loginService: LoginService, cookieService: CookieService, …}
```

i need to catch this "MyComponent" value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At that point `$event` is a simple javascript object.

To get class name, you can type `$event.constructor.name` which will result in `MyComponent`.